# Window resize doesn't effect contents

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, glfw

I have an issue with resizing my window on LWJGL3 and GLFW. I can resize the window, however what is rendered to it does not size with it, most likely a coordinate issue. I've listed my Display and Main classes.

```
public static void init() {
    // Setup an error callback. The default implementation
    // will print the error message in System.err.
    GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set();

    // Initialize GLFW. Most GLFW functions will not work before doing this.
    if ( !glfwInit() )
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");

    // Configure GLFW
    glfwDefaultWindowHints(); // optional, the current window hints are already the default
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE); // the window will stay hidden after creation
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE); // the window will be resizable

    // Create the window
    window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 500, "Game Indev", NULL, NULL);
    if ( window == NULL )
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");

    // Setup a key callback. It will be called every time a key is pressed, repeated or released.
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, (window, key, scancode, action, mods) -> {
        if ( key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE )
            glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true); // We will detect this in the rendering loop
    });

    // Get the thread stack and push a new frame
    try ( MemoryStack stack = stackPush() ) {
        IntBuffer pWidth = stack.mallocInt(1); // int*
        IntBuffer pHeight = stack.mallocInt(1); // int*

        // Get the window size passed to glfwCreateWindow
        glfwGetWindowSize(window, pWidth, pHeight);

        // Get the resolution of the primary monitor
        GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());

        // Center the window
        glfwSetWindowPos(
                window,
                (vidmode.width() - pWidth.get(0)) / 2,
                (vidmode.height() - pHeight.get(0)) / 2
        );
    } // the stack frame is popped automatically

    // Make the OpenGL context current
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    // Enable v-sync
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    // Make the window visible
    glfwShowWindow(window);
}
```

And my main class is here:

```
// The window handle

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Version.getVersion());

    Display.init();

    Loader loader = new Loader();
    Renderer renderer = new Renderer();
    // This line checks the context and capabilities
    GL.createCapabilities();
    float[] vertices = {

            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0f,
            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0f
    };
    RawModel model = loader.loadToVao(vertices);

    // Set the clear color initially
    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    /*
    THIS
    IS
    THE
    MAIN
    GAME
    LOGIC
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */
    while ( !glfwWindowShouldClose(Display.window) ) {
        GL11.glClearColor(GameState.stateR, GameState.stateG, GameState.stateB, GameState.stateA);
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        renderer.renderModel(model);

        glfwSwapBuffers(Display.window); // swap the color buffers


        GameState.getStateInput();
        GameState.renderGameState(loader, renderer);
        glfwPollEvents();

    }

    //End of main loop -----------------------------------------------------------------

    // Free the window callbacks and destroy the window
    glfwFreeCallbacks(Display.window);
    glfwDestroyWindow(Display.window);

    // Terminate GLFW and free the error callback
    glfwTerminate();
    glfwSetErrorCallback(null).free();
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I also have an image of what Im talking about.

[Before resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/to2Xt.png)
[After resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohBEV.png)
Obviously, I would want the quad to resize with the screen, making the fullscreen mode have a large quad in the middle, rather than the same size in the bottom left coordinates. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the contents of the window to resize properly you need to respond to the resize of the window with:

```
glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(window, new GLFWWindowSizeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void invoke(long window, int argWidth, int argHeight) {
            resizeWindow(argWidth, argHeight);
        }
});
```

In resizeWindow(argWidth, argHeight) you need to set the viewport and to recalculate the projection matrix (only if you are using one).

```
private void resizeWindow(int argWidth, int argHeight) {
    glViewport(0, 0, argWidth,argHeight);

    adjustProjectionMatrix(width, height); // recalculating projection matrix (only if you are using one)
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you are using LWJGL 2 :

```
if (Display.wasResized()) {
    GL11.glViewport(0, 0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());

    adjustProjectionMatrix(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight()); // only if you are using one
}
```

Comment: I don't exactly understand the syntax here, this code throws lots of errors when put into my own, most likely due to the GLFWWindowSizeCallback object being an extension of an abstract class or something. How do I fix this? Thanks in advance. @tymo tymo

Comment: Are you using LWJGL 2 or 3, because this is written in LWJGL 3. GLFWWindowSizeCallback doesn't exist in LWJGL 2.

Comment: Ok so I was able to get the code to not throw any errors and run the program, however the quad just disappears when I resize the window @tymo tymo

Comment: Are you using shaders. Maybe something is wrong with the projection matrix (the calculation of it). For me everything works fine.